# can i put fn::join inside fn::if statement in cftemplate formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, devops

I have a situation where i have my application deployed in different environment (prod and stage) . 
i have a common cftemplate.json with following parameter

```
"Parameters" : {
    "EnvType" : {
      "Description" : "Environment type.",
      "Default" : "test",
      "Type" : "String",
      "AllowedValues" : ["prod", "stage"],
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must specify prod or test."
    }
  },

  "Conditions" : {
    "CreateProdResources" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "EnvType"}, "prod"]}
  },
```

Now i have a alarm ,

```
"AppServerHealthCheckAlarm":{
     "Type":"AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
     "Properties":{
        "AlarmName" : {"Fn::Join" : ["", [
           {"Ref" : "AppId"}, ",",
           {"Ref" : "AppServerAG"}, ":", "HealthCheck", ",", "MAJOR"]]},
 ------
 ------
 ------
  }
},
```

Now i want to put this fn::join inside fn::if condition so that for prod it should be major and for stage it should be minor .

How should i configure it

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of wrapping `Fn::Join` inside a `Fn::If`, the other way around is better. This should work just fine:

```
{
    "AlarmName":
    {"Fn::Join": ["",
                  [{"Ref" : "AppId"},
                   ",",
                   {"Ref" : "AppServerAG"},
                   ":",
                   "HealthCheck",
                   ",",
                   {"Fn::If": ["CreateProdResources", "MAJOR", "MINOR"]}
                  ]
    ]}
}
```